# Consume Swift Passbase SDK with ObjC

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, appdelegate

I am attempting to use the Passbase SDK(Swift) with Objective-C.

So far, here's the code I have:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "objCApp-Swift.h"
#import <Passbase/Passbase.h>

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    PassbaseSDK.initialize("myPassbaseToken")
    
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    
    return YES;
}
```

This is the line that causes the error. I'm not sure how to proceed.

**`PassbaseSDK.initialize("myPassbaseToken")`**

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the error?  Shouldn't it be something like `[PassbaseSDK initialise:@"myPassbaseToken"]`

Comment: Thanks for responding... tried this... getting this error... "No known class method for selector 'initialize:'"

Comment: Look at the h file to see what the methods are.

Comment: There is no .h file! https://github.com/passbase/passbase-sdk/find/master

Comment: You are including one, so Xcode has generated one somewhere. Check derived data

Comment: checked DerivedData, no luck finding the .h file. I'm stumped. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qigh7qjgy3gqf23/Screen%20Shot%202022-01-22%20at%209.08.39%20AM.png?dl=0)

Comment: The Passbase library was installed with CocoaPods... there are no visible methods...

Comment: OK... I found this .h file. Now what? https://www.dropbox.com/s/ww1mtgnr7j9mu1x/Passbase-Swift.h?dl=0

Comment: Found this method in the .h file. Not sure how to access it with ObjC. `SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC8Passbase11PassbaseSDK")   @interface PassbaseSDK : NSObject
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end`

Comment: That is an instance initialiser. The `initialize` method that you need to call is a class function. You may find it easier to write your own Swift wrapper class that you can call from your Objective C