# Using Swift Framework with Objective-C (Passbase)

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

Installing PassbaseSDK(Swift) into an Objective-C project.

The SDK framework uses this .h file.

```
// Generated by Apple Swift version 5.5.1 (swiftlang-1300.0.31.4 clang-1300.0.29.6)
#ifndef PASSBASE_SWIFT_H
#define PASSBASE_SWIFT_H
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wgcc-compat"

#if !defined(__has_include)
# define __has_include(x) 0
#endif
#if !defined(__has_attribute)
# define __has_attribute(x) 0
#endif
#if !defined(__has_feature)
# define __has_feature(x) 0
#endif
#if !defined(__has_warning)
# define __has_warning(x) 0
#endif

#if __has_include(<swift/objc-prologue.h>)
# include <swift/objc-prologue.h>
#endif

#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wauto-import"
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#if !defined(SWIFT_TYPEDEFS)
# define SWIFT_TYPEDEFS 1
# if __has_include(<uchar.h>)
#  include <uchar.h>
# elif !defined(__cplusplus)
typedef uint_least16_t char16_t;
typedef uint_least32_t char32_t;
# endif
typedef float swift_float2  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(2)));
typedef float swift_float3  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(3)));
typedef float swift_float4  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(4)));
typedef double swift_double2  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(2)));
typedef double swift_double3  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(3)));
typedef double swift_double4  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(4)));
typedef int swift_int2  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(2)));
typedef int swift_int3  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(3)));
typedef int swift_int4  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(4)));
typedef unsigned int swift_uint2  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(2)));
typedef unsigned int swift_uint3  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(3)));
typedef unsigned int swift_uint4  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(4)));
#endif

#if !defined(SWIFT_PASTE)
# define SWIFT_PASTE_HELPER(x, y) x##y
# define SWIFT_PASTE(x, y) SWIFT_PASTE_HELPER(x, y)
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_METATYPE)
# define SWIFT_METATYPE(X) Class
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_CLASS_PROPERTY)
# if __has_feature(objc_class_property)
#  define SWIFT_CLASS_PROPERTY(...) __VA_ARGS__
# else
#  define SWIFT_CLASS_PROPERTY(...)
# endif
#endif

#if __has_attribute(objc_runtime_name)
# define SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(X) __attribute__((objc_runtime_name(X)))
#else
# define SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(X)
#endif
#if __has_attribute(swift_name)
# define SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(X) __attribute__((swift_name(X)))
#else
# define SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(X)
#endif
#if __has_attribute(objc_method_family)
# define SWIFT_METHOD_FAMILY(X) __attribute__((objc_method_family(X)))
#else
# define SWIFT_METHOD_FAMILY(X)
#endif
#if __has_attribute(noescape)
# define SWIFT_NOESCAPE __attribute__((noescape))
#else
# define SWIFT_NOESCAPE
#endif
#if __has_attribute(ns_consumed)
# define SWIFT_RELEASES_ARGUMENT __attribute__((ns_consumed))
#else
# define SWIFT_RELEASES_ARGUMENT
#endif
#if __has_attribute(warn_unused_result)
# define SWIFT_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
#else
# define SWIFT_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT
#endif
#if __has_attribute(noreturn)
# define SWIFT_NORETURN __attribute__((noreturn))
#else
# define SWIFT_NORETURN
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA)
# define SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA)
# define SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_ENUM_EXTRA)
# define SWIFT_ENUM_EXTRA
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_CLASS)
# if __has_attribute(objc_subclassing_restricted)
#  define SWIFT_CLASS(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) __attribute__((objc_subclassing_restricted)) SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
#  define SWIFT_CLASS_NAMED(SWIFT_NAME) __attribute__((objc_subclassing_restricted)) SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
# else
#  define SWIFT_CLASS(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
#  define SWIFT_CLASS_NAMED(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
# endif
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_RESILIENT_CLASS)
# if __has_attribute(objc_class_stub)
#  define SWIFT_RESILIENT_CLASS(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_CLASS(SWIFT_NAME) __attribute__((objc_class_stub))
#  define SWIFT_RESILIENT_CLASS_NAMED(SWIFT_NAME) __attribute__((objc_class_stub)) SWIFT_CLASS_NAMED(SWIFT_NAME)
# else
#  define SWIFT_RESILIENT_CLASS(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_CLASS(SWIFT_NAME)
#  define SWIFT_RESILIENT_CLASS_NAMED(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_CLASS_NAMED(SWIFT_NAME)
# endif
#endif

#if !defined(SWIFT_PROTOCOL)
# define SWIFT_PROTOCOL(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA
# define SWIFT_PROTOCOL_NAMED(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA
#endif

#if !defined(SWIFT_EXTENSION)
# define SWIFT_EXTENSION(M) SWIFT_PASTE(M##_Swift_, __LINE__)
#endif

#if !defined(OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER)
# if __has_attribute(objc_designated_initializer)
#  define OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER __attribute__((objc_designated_initializer))
# else
#  define OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER
# endif
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_ENUM_ATTR)
# if defined(__has_attribute) && __has_attribute(enum_extensibility)
#  define SWIFT_ENUM_ATTR(_extensibility) __attribute__((enum_extensibility(_extensibility)))
# else
#  define SWIFT_ENUM_ATTR(_extensibility)
# endif
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_ENUM)
# define SWIFT_ENUM(_type, _name, _extensibility) enum _name : _type _name; enum SWIFT_ENUM_ATTR(_extensibility) SWIFT_ENUM_EXTRA _name : _type
# if __has_feature(generalized_swift_name)
#  define SWIFT_ENUM_NAMED(_type, _name, SWIFT_NAME, _extensibility) enum _name : _type _name SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(SWIFT_NAME); enum SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_ENUM_ATTR(_extensibility) SWIFT_ENUM_EXTRA _name : _type
# else
#  define SWIFT_ENUM_NAMED(_type, _name, SWIFT_NAME, _extensibility) SWIFT_ENUM(_type, _name, _extensibility)
# endif
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE)
# define SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE __attribute__((unavailable))
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE_MSG)
# define SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE_MSG(msg) __attribute__((unavailable(msg)))
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_AVAILABILITY)
# define SWIFT_AVAILABILITY(plat, ...) __attribute__((availability(plat, __VA_ARGS__)))
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_WEAK_IMPORT)
# define SWIFT_WEAK_IMPORT __attribute__((weak_import))
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_DEPRECATED)
# define SWIFT_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_DEPRECATED_MSG)
# define SWIFT_DEPRECATED_MSG(...) __attribute__((deprecated(__VA_ARGS__)))
#endif
#if __has_feature(attribute_diagnose_if_objc)
# define SWIFT_DEPRECATED_OBJC(Msg) __attribute__((diagnose_if(1, Msg, "warning")))
#else
# define SWIFT_DEPRECATED_OBJC(Msg) SWIFT_DEPRECATED_MSG(Msg)
#endif
#if !defined(IBSegueAction)
# define IBSegueAction
#endif
#if __has_feature(modules)
#if __has_warning("-Watimport-in-framework-header")
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Watimport-in-framework-header"
#endif
@import CoreGraphics;
@import ObjectiveC;
@import UIKit;
#endif

#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wproperty-attribute-mismatch"
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wduplicate-method-arg"
#if __has_warning("-Wpragma-clang-attribute")
# pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wpragma-clang-attribute"
#endif
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunknown-pragmas"
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wnullability"

#if __has_attribute(external_source_symbol)
# pragma push_macro("any")
# undef any
# pragma clang attribute push(__attribute__((external_source_symbol(language="Swift", defined_in="Passbase",generated_declaration))), apply_to=any(function,enum,objc_interface,objc_category,objc_protocol))
# pragma pop_macro("any")
#endif

@class NSCoder;
@class NSNumber;
@class UITouch;
@class UIEvent;

/// Lottie comes prepacked with a two Animated Controls, <code>AnimatedSwitch</code> and
/// <code>AnimatedButton</code>. Both of these controls are built on top of <code>AnimatedControl</code>
/// <code>AnimatedControl</code> is a subclass of <code>UIControl</code> that provides an interactive
/// mechanism for controlling the visual state of an animation in response to
/// user actions.
/// The <code>AnimatedControl</code> will show and hide layers depending on the current
/// <code>UIControl.State</code> of the control.
/// Users of <code>AnimationControl</code> can set a Layer Name for each <code>UIControl.State</code>.
/// When the state is change the <code>AnimationControl</code> will change the visibility
/// of its layers.
/// NOTE: Do not initialize directly. This is intended to be subclassed.
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC8Passbase15AnimatedControl")
@interface AnimatedControl : UIControl
- (nonnull instancetype)init SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE;
+ (nonnull instancetype)new SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE_MSG("-init is unavailable");
- (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder * _Nonnull)aDecoder OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@property (nonatomic, getter=isEnabled) BOOL enabled;
@property (nonatomic, getter=isSelected) BOOL selected;
@property (nonatomic, getter=isHighlighted) BOOL highlighted;
- (BOOL)beginTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch * _Nonnull)touch withEvent:(UIEvent * _Nullable)event SWIFT_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT;
- (BOOL)continueTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch * _Nonnull)touch withEvent:(UIEvent * _Nullable)event SWIFT_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT;
- (void)endTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch * _Nullable)touch withEvent:(UIEvent * _Nullable)event;
- (void)cancelTrackingWithEvent:(UIEvent * _Nullable)event;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGSize intrinsicContentSize;
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE;
@end


/// A view that can be added to a keypath of an AnimationView
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC8Passbase16AnimationSubview")
@interface AnimationSubview : UIView
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder * _Nonnull)coder OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end


/// An Objective-C compatible wrapper around Lottie’s Animation class.
/// Use in tandem with CompatibleAnimationView when using Lottie in Objective-C
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC8Passbase19CompatibleAnimation")
@interface CompatibleAnimation : NSObject
- (nonnull instancetype)init SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE;
+ (nonnull instancetype)new SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE_MSG("-init is unavailable");
@end


/// An Objective-C compatible wrapper around Lottie’s AnimationKeypath
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC8Passbase26CompatibleAnimationKeypath")
@interface CompatibleAnimationKeypath : NSObject
- (nonnull instancetype)init SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE;
+ (nonnull instancetype)new SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE_MSG("-init is unavailable");
@end


/// An Objective-C compatible wrapper around Lottie’s AnimationView.
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC8Passbase23CompatibleAnimationView")
@interface CompatibleAnimationView : UIView
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE;
- (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder * _Nonnull)aDecoder SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE;
@property (nonatomic) UIViewContentMode contentMode;
@end


SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC8Passbase10LottieView")
@interface LottieView : UIView
- (void)didMoveToWindow;
@property (nonatomic) UIViewContentMode contentMode;
- (void)layoutSubviews;
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder * _Nonnull)coder OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end


SWIFT_PROTOCOL("_TtP8Passbase25NavigationBarViewDelegate_")
@protocol NavigationBarViewDelegate
- (void)didClickBackNavigationButton;
@optional
- (void)didClickCloseNavigationButton;
@end


SWIFT_CLASS_NAMED("PassbaseButton")
@interface PassbaseButton : UIButton
- (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder * _Nonnull)aDecoder SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE;
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (void)awakeFromNib;
@end


SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC8Passbase11PassbaseSDK")
@interface PassbaseSDK : NSObject
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end


#if __has_attribute(external_source_symbol)
# pragma clang attribute pop
#endif
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
#endif
```

The sample Swift code calls this method in the AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        PassbaseSDK.initialize(publishableApiKey: "passbaseToken")
        
        return true
    }
```

My problem is, since there is no (void) function for "PassbaseSDK", I do not know how to initialize the 'passbaseToken' in the Objective-C code.

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC8Passbase11PassbaseSDK")
@interface PassbaseSDK : NSObject
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

How should I go about initializing my passbaseToken in ObjC?

**Update: It's been suggested I write my own Swift-wrapper class that is called from my ObjC. I need more information on how to do this, exactly. All my attempts have failed, miserably.**

Comment: You can do `PassbaseSDK *sdk = [[PassbaseSDK] init];`, but that's all, there is no APIKey property, not method function (it's not about the "void" function), nor "prefillUserEmail" visible. Might want to contact them.

Comment: I tried contacting them, no response. :-(

Comment: @Larme, it's been suggested I write my own Swift-wrapper class that is called from my ObjC. All my attempts to do this have failed, miserably. Any suggestions on how to do this properly?

Comment: Write a wrapper as they say in Swift. Show your attempts, and we might help...

Comment: You shouldn't need much more than https://gist.github.com/paulw11/7772e98743bcf39407e2bad884018330. And then you can just call `[MyPassbaseWrapper initialise: @"key"]`

Comment: You rock! Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Consume Swift Passbase SDK with ObjC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70808886/consume-swift-passbase-sdk-with-objc)